# Print a function name within a function

Tags: php, codeigniter, optimization

IS it possible to print a function's name within the same function

for example how could i do the following;

```
public function site()
   {
       $this->load->model('model_get');
       $data["results"] = $this->model_get->getData("**FUNCTION_NAME**");
       $this->load->view('view_head', $data);
   }
```

The model will pull entries with a matching field from a pre-configured table and then pass it to the view and echo the output.

Comment: i would love to know what this has to do with "optimization"

Comment: If i can print a function name within a function i can have a separate controller manage the above by instead of copying and modifying it for every new page.

Comment: The `__FUNCTION__` [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)?

Comment: That worked great thanks Mark! Can you _formally_ answer so I can credit you accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within a function:

```
function helloWorld() {
    echo __FUNCTION__, PHP_EOL;
}

helloWorld();
```

displays

```
helloWorld
```

From within a class method:

```
class Hello {
    public static function world() {
        echo __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
    }
}

Hello::world();
```

displays

```
Hello::world
```

From within a class method:

```
class Hello {
    public static function world() {
        echo __FUNCTION__, PHP_EOL;
    }
}

Hello::world();
```

displays

```
world
```

The two constants work equally when called for non-static methods using normal class calls for an instantiated class